# How to know if a map is a sub-map of another in Scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary

I've two maps, and i need to know if all the elements in map1 are in map2 also.
I think that using sets is a good idea but this doesn't work.

```
map1 = Map("provider" -> pepe, "consumer" -> pipo)
map2 = Map("provider" -> pepe, "consumer" -> pipo, "id" -> 1)

map1.toSet subsetOf map2.toSet
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Scala, how to check if a Map contains all entries from another Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189198/in-scala-how-to-check-if-a-map-contains-all-entries-from-another-map)

Comment: What is type of pepe and pipo?

Comment: Why it does not work?

Comment: In what sense does it "not work" then? It returns `true` as expected.

Comment: does pepe and pipo returns random number?

Comment: Scala will come up with strangest possible type signatures for those `toSet` results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified what is the type of `pepe` and `pipo` but let's assume they've got the same type and it's `String`. When you use `map1.toSet` it would create a set with inferred type `Set[(String, String)]`. Your other map contains also integer so type would be `Set[(String, Any)]`. So your code won't compile because types don't match. One way to solve it would be just specifying type:

```
map1.toSet[(String, Any)].subsetOf(map2.toSet)
```